# Best way to develop asp.net web application with specific user rights

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, permissions

I'm developing a web application wich needs access to a specific directory on one of our servers. When the application is deployed it will run as a specific 'user' (configured in the IIS Application Pool) with access permissions to the given directory.

While developing/debugging the application with Visual Studio 2010's built-in webserver, the application has no permissions to the directory.

What would be the best way to develop/debug this application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "built-in webserver" you mean cassini?
If so just deploy the site on the machine's IIS the website project properties.

IIS Express is also an option but I prefer to develop on an environment closest as possible to the one I have in production and IIS is the key service I want to make sure won't give me any deployment problems.

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Although I don't really like the option of using my machine's IIS (which is why is started this question), it seems like it's the only option. Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you like to use your machine's IIS?

Comment: Because when a new colleague has to work on the same application, he needs to install and configure IIS before he can debug. I just like the simplicity of the built-in server.